# How to get only the objects meeting one criteria in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have example collection:

```
db.books.find()

{ "author" : "Coetzee", "is_favourite" : true, "version" : 1 }
{ "author" : "Coetzee", "is_favourite" : true, "version" : 1 }
{ "author" : "Coetzee", "is_favourite" : false, "version" : 2 }
{ "author" : "King", "is_favourite" : false, "version" : 2 }
{ "author" : "Cohen", "is_favourite" : true, "version" : 2 }
{ "author" : "Cohen", "is_favourite" : false, "version" : 3 }
{ "author" : "Picasso", "is_favourite" : true, "version" : 3 }
```

by running this:

```
    db.books.aggregate([ 
{ $match: {"is_favourite":{ $ne: true}}}, 
{ $group: { _id: "$author"}}
])
```

I get the following:

```
{ "_id" : "Cohen" }
{ "_id" : "King" }
{ "_id" : "Coetzee" }
```

what should I do to get only the objects meeting `"is_favourte": false`?
In this particular case I'm interested in getting only `"author": "King"`

Comment: Your criteria to filter out the data is incomplete as per your expectations. Because Author Cohen has two records with is_favourite : true and false both.

Comment: You have authors "Coetzee," "King," and "Cohen" all within documents where `is_favourite` is false. So, your query is working as expected. The only way you'd get *only* author "Cohen" is if you also limited your match to `version` = 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want author where is_favourite is always false, you could use this :

```
    db.books.aggregate([
       {
          $group:{
             _id:"$author",
             is_fav:{
                $push:"$is_favourite"
             }
          }
       },
       {
          $match:{
             is_fav:{
                $nin:[
                   true
                ]
             }
          }
       },
       {
          $project:{
             _id:1
          }
       }
    ],{
      allowDiskUse: true
})
```

returns

```
{ "_id" : "King" }
```

Comment: It works exactly how I want to. I have edited my question so it's clear now. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? I'm working on huge db and having $group at the first place, makes it too big:
 "errmsg" : "exception: Exceeded memory limit for $group

If you have any other clues, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: @grela oh ok you just need to allowDiskUse, it's verry simple, see my edit